# F-related fields

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

Please help me show how a field $X = \frac{d}{dt}$ is $F$-related to
$$
Y = x \frac{\partial}{\partial y} 
- y \frac{\partial}{\partial x}. 
$$
where $F(t) = (\cos t, \cos 2t)$.

I need to show the relatedness.

Comment: You have to put your LaTeX code between dollar signs (\$). So " \$a \times b\$" will produce $a \times b$.

Comment: Edit your post to include exactly what you must show (in the form of an equation) and show your efforts/progress to show that. Are you sure the problem is correctly stated?

Comment: Consider looking at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/598203/a-specific-example-of-f-related-vector-fields